# How to align widget with Wrap

Tags: flutter, widget

I want to align image with the text. I have modified the code to make it happen, but it doesn't show any change.
Below I attach my code, sorry I delete the photo of my error because to personal reason.

```
Column(
        children: [
          SizedBox(
            width: 350,
            child: Wrap(
              alignment: WrapAlignment.start,
              direction: Axis.horizontal,
              crossAxisAlignment: WrapCrossAlignment.center,
              children: [
                SvgPicture.asset(
                  Assets.icons.image9.path,
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                ),
                Wrap(
                  children: [
                    Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15),
                      child: Text(
                        'Roy',
                        style: heading3(
                          color: ColorName.neutralBackgroundWhite,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
...
                    onSelected: (_) {},
                    child: SvgPicture.asset(Assets.icons.moreVertical.path),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(width: 17),
                Text(
                  'Code : 6666',
                  style: body1(color: ColorName.neutralBackgroundWhite),
                ),
              ],
            ),
```

Comment: i think you cant achive that with wrap. because with wrap: widget children will automatically move to the next line.

you can combine `Row` and `Column` if you want static position

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use wrap, as it will go horizontal to vertical, if mobile device does not have enough space. You have to use Rows and Column instead, check the bottom code for implementation and screenshot:

```
Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 14.0, vertical: 16.0),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.blue[900],
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12)
          ),
          // width: 350,
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: [
              SizedBox(
                height: 60,
                child: Row(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                        image: const DecorationImage(image: NetworkImage('https://cartoonavatar.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/12/02-300x300.png')),
                      ),
                      width: 60,
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(width: 10),
                    Expanded(
                      child: Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                        children: const [
                          Text('Gekyume Onfroy', maxLines:1, overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.white)),
                          Spacer(),
                          Text('Access Code : 6666', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14, color: Colors.white),)
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(width: 10),
                    IconButton(padding: EdgeInsets.zero, onPressed: () {}, icon: const Icon(Icons.more_vert, color: Colors.white))
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 10),
              const Divider(color: Colors.white, thickness: 2,),
              const SizedBox(height: 10),
              Row(
                children: [
                  const Icon(Icons.call, color: Colors.white),
                  const SizedBox(width: 10),
                  const Text('628-123-456-666', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
                  const Spacer(),
                  Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8, vertical: 4),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.blue[300],
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4)
                    ),
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: const [
                        Text('Last Activity', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),),
                        Icon(Icons.navigate_next, color: Colors.white, size: 14,)
                      ],
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I thought Wrap can be used anytime, but now I see it clearly.